# Android: Error in retrieving image from uri

Tags: java, android, bitmap

In my Android application user can enter a profile picture. I have a predefined database in my assets folder. It has a table named Person. In the Person table there is a field Profile Picture which has BLOB type. I've saved the profile picture in the database using its' uri. I've used following code segment for retrieving uri of the image.

```
String path = null;
path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap,
                "title", null);

Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);

String uriString = imageUri.toString() ;            

person.setProfilePic(uriString);

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(COLUMN_PROFILE_PICTURE, person.getProfilePic());
```

This is my entity class segment.

```
public class Person {
private int id;
private String profilePic;
private String name, date_of_birth, age, gender, bloodGrp;

......

public String getProfilePic() {
    return profilePic;
}

public void setProfilePic(String imageInByte) {
    this.profilePic = imageInByte;
}
```

I've retrieved person data from database by using this method.

```
public ArrayList<Person> getPersonList() {
    ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();

    String sql = "SELECT p.PersonName, p.ProfilePicture, p.DOB "
            + "FROM EMPerson p " + "ORDER BY p.PersonName ";
    System.out.println(sql);
    ArrayList<?> stringList = selectRecordsFromDB(sql, null);

    for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<?> arrayList = (ArrayList<?>) stringList.get(i);
        ArrayList<?> list = arrayList;
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName((String) list.get(0));
        person.setProfilePic((String) list.get(1));
        person.setDate_of_birth((String) list.get(2));

        personList.add(person);

    }

    return personList;

}
```

I've used following method to get Bitmap from the url.

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    Log.d("getBitmap", "getBitmap");
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        URL aURL = new URL(url);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(aURL.openConnection().getInputStream());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    return bm;
}
```

I am calling this getBitmap method and set the bitmap in an image view as following.

```
Bitmap image;
image = getBitmap(i.getProfilePic());
proPic.setImageBitmap(image);
```

This is my CUstomAdapter class.

```
package my.easymedi.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import my.easymedi.entity.Person;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {
private ArrayList<Person> lstPerson;
private Context my_context;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Person> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.lstPerson = objects;
    my_context = context;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // assign the view we are converting to a local variable
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    Person i = lstPerson.get(position);

    if (i != null) {

        TextView personName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.personName);
        ImageView proPic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgProPic);
        TextView dob = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dateOfBirth);

        if (personName != null) {
            personName.setText(i.getName());
        }
        if (proPic != null) {
            Bitmap image;

            image = getBitmap(i.getProfilePic());

            proPic.setImageBitmap(image);

        }
        if (dob != null) {
            dob.setText(i.getDate_of_birth());
        }
    }

    return v;

}
public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    Log.d("getBitmap", "getBitmap");
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        Uri aURL = null;// new URL(url);
        Uri.parse(url);

        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(my_context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(aURL));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    return bm;
}
```

}

But the problem is Image view is empty. Even though log cat doesn't show any error message. I am testing with an emulator. Can anyone plz be so kind enough to explain what's going on here ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `aURL.openConnection().getInputStream()`, you should use `getContentResolver().openInputStream(aURL)` to retrieve data from a content URI.

Comment: I'm using this getBitmap method inside a CustomAdapter class which is extended from ArrayAdapter<object>. When I use getContentResolver() inside this CustomAdapter class it shows an error (The method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type CustomAdapter)

Comment: `getContentResolver()` is a method of `Context` which you should have available (or can pass it in via the constructor) in your Adapter.